# Rails has_many_through undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a has_many_through relationship and am getting an "undefined local variable" exception when I pull up the localhost:300/lists.

I have Listables - which are made up of Lists, Sources and Elements.

Listables Model:

```
class Listable < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :lists
belongs_to :sources
belongs_to :elements
end
```

Source Model:

```
class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :listables
has_many :lists, through => :listables
has_many :elements, through => :listables
end
```

Elements Model:

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :listables
has_many :lists, through => :listables
has_many :sources, through => :listables
end
```

Lists Model:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :listables
has_many :sources, through => :listables
has_many :elements, through => :listables
end
```

Comment: Look at the trace dump that rails provides and see what variable is being flagged and what module and line its in.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the type after `belongs_to` should be singular, not plural as you have it. E.g. try this:

```
class Listable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :source
  belongs_to :element
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

Answer (score 0):

The lines has_many :sources, through => :listables need a : before the through. So it should read:

```
has_many :sources, :through => :listables
```